# Beamer Slide header is not including subsubsection

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using beamer to make my slides. I managed to have the subsections show in the header. For example subsection of Security is (1) Background (2) PerSpectron (3) Commercial ....

How can I add `subsubsections` in the header too? For example, I want to have several subsections to the background appear in an extra column in the header, similar to `subsections`. Is there any way to do this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: By design beamer discourages the use of subsubsections to avoid too deep nesting of content. Even in the places in which subsubsections are implemented, their support is often only rudimentary.

Comment: To quote the beamer user guide: "Do not use subsubsections, they are evil."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd like to quote the beamer users guide:

> "Do not use subsubsections, they are evil."

If you want to torture your audience, you can use this quick hack. Make sure that:

- you have more sections/subsections than subsubsections, otherwise the height might be wrong
- you set the counter for the number of subsubsection in each subsection

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{totalsubsub}

\AtBeginSubsubsection[]{\label{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\thesubsubsection}}


\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.33\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.34\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.33\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=3.3ex,wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
    \begin{minipage}[b][\@tempdimb][c]{.9\linewidth}%
      \ifnum\thetotalsubsub>0
          \foreach \i in {1,...,\thetotalsubsub}{% 
                  \ifnum\i=\thesubsubsection
                      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar}
                  \else
                      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}
                  \fi
                  \hyperlink{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\i}{\nameref{subsubsec:\thesection:\thesubsection:\i}}\par
              }
      \fi
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%    
  \fi%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{sub 1}
\setcounter{totalsubsub}{3}

\subsubsection{subsub 1}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 1
\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsub 2}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 2
\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsub 3}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 3
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub 2}
\setcounter{totalsubsub}{0}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\subsection{sub 3}
\setcounter{totalsubsub}{2}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{subsub 1}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 1
\end{frame} 

\subsubsection{subsub 2}
\begin{frame}
    subsub 2
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you.  This works fantastic. Do you know what is the best way to adjust the width of the section, subsection and sub-sub-section window at the top? For example, larger space for section, medium for subsection and smaller for subsubsection. Thank you.

Comment: @parisa Each of the colorboxes currently has a `wd=.33\paperwidth`, modify that as you like